# Prevent IOS from automatically decompressing downloaded GZIP data?

Tags: ios, nsurl

In my app I have custom data structures that are saved to a file with GZIP compression.

However, upon importing this data back into the app (via "Open with > My App" and the `(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url` function of `UIApplication`), the file is moved into my app's folder in a decompressed state.

This is undesired behavior, I'd want the file to stay compressed. But, I'm unsure of where I even have the possibility of telling the system to download the file in this manner?

This happens when the user downloads/opens such files from apps like Safari, Firefox, and even from Mail attachments.

Comment: I would start by changing the file extension. If the file is supposed to be a blackbox, don't tell the system it's a compressed file. If that does not help, add a few bytes at the start of the file to prevent any automatic checking of the file type.

Comment: @Sulthan this isn't a bad idea, a bit of a roundabout approach but it worked thx